# Not able to load Kibana on port 5601

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have installed Elasticsearch, Logstash, Kibana and Nginx following this guide,

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana-elk-stack-on-ubuntu-14-04

Elasticsearch is running on 9200

But running

```
curl http://localhost:5601
```

returns this:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 5601: Connection refused
```

In `kibana.yml` file I configured

```
server.port: 5601

server.host: "127.0.0.1"
```

Here I also checked with `localhost` and `aws private ip address`.

And while checking the port running this:

```
netstat -anp | grep 5601
```

I am getting:

```
(No info could be read for "-p": geteuid()=1000 but you should be root.)
```

I can start kibana running:

```
sudo service kibana start
```

But while checking status using:

```
sudo service kibana status
```

I get:

```
kibana is not running
```

I haven't setup firewall and running

```
sudo ufw status
```

Returns:

```
Status : Inactive
```

I am confused, why is  the kibana port not listening?

Comment: I think configuration only the problem, change your server.host to your IP address

Comment: check this URL http://127.0.0.1:5601

Comment: Try running Kibana in the foreground: `which kibana` or `whereis kibana` and run the Kibana binary. Then look at the output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check Kibana logs for why it is not starting at all. You may find things like kibana unable to connect elasticsearch at given url.

Answer (score 3):

Its running now.
When I checked kibana log (`vi /var/log/kibana/kibana.stderr`)

**Error: EACCES, permission denied '/opt/kibana/optimize/.babelcache.json'**

So I changed permission for the file .babelcache.json

```
sudo chown -R kibana:root /opt/kibana/optimize/.babelcache.json
```

Then restarted kibana , and this solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously the problem is that `Kibana` is not running. There are several things that you could try to resolve this:

- Try to reinstall `Kibana`.
- The default settings in `kibana.yml` should be enough to get `Kibana` up and running. Just be sure that you uncomment the `elasticsearch.url` entry and let it point to `"http://localhost:9200"`.
- The other thing you could check is the `Elasticsearch` and `Kibana` version compatibility. To check if you are using the right version for them please go to [this link](https://www.elastic.co/support/matrix#show_compatibility), click on `product compatibility` and read the details under ***Supported Kibana Versions***.

Comment: .  Reinstalled kibana. (I didn't remove kibana before reinstall)

Comment: .  Uncomented 'elasticsearch.url' 
.  Kibana version is supported.
No luck still.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but if by any chance you are here because you are having this same situation:

> I can start kibana running:
>
> `sudo service kibana start`
>
> But while checking status using:
>
> `sudo service kibana status`
>   I get:
>
> `kibana is not running`

And you get the `Kibana server is not ready yet` with an error on Kibana logs that states:
**`FATAL Error: Port 5601 is already in use. Another instance of Kibana may be running!`**

You need to check [this part of documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/rpm.html#_sysv_literal_init_literal_vs_literal_systemd_literal_2)

For example, if you run

`ps -p 1`

And it gives you `systemctl`, you shouldn´t try to run Kibana service with `sudo service kibana start`.

So, first run `sudo service kibana stop` and then `sudo systemctl start kibana`.

I know this might be really obvious to some, specially with the documentation addressing the situation, yet i have been found on this situation by human oversight and hope the experience will help someone out there.

Answer (score 0):

For me helped solution from 
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/kibana-5601-connection-refused/103641/2

```
 /opt/kibana/bin/kibana & disown
```